# Can't bind to property of child component as variable hasn't loaded?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component with a child, and I am wanting to pass a variable to the child, but the variable takes a second or two to load properly from a `subscribe`.

I have given an *ngIf but I still get the error:

> Can't bind to 'event' since it isn't a known property of 'app-race-card'.

Is this because of the time it takes to actually load the event from the subscribe or am I missing something bigger?

I figured that putting an `*ngIf="event"` in the element call for the `<app-race-card>` call would mean that it would wait until `event` was populated before attempting to load the component, and then actually pass what was now present?

**event.component.ts**

```
let event;

ngOnInit() {
   this.subscribeService();
}

subscribeService() {
    this.service.eventSubject
    .subscribe(res => this.event = res);
  }
```

**event.component.html**

```
<comp *ngIf="event" [event]="event"></comp>
```

**comp.component.ts**

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  @Input() event: IEvent;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Does it work if you just say `<app-race-card *ngIf="event"></app-race-card>`?

Comment: in event.component you have 'let' event. try with public or private I don't think let will work.  i.e declare as "public event;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Most likelly** (you don't show what `this.eventService.eventSubject` is actually doing), you are confused about how Change Detection runs. Your `eventSubject`(as name suggests) probably reacts to some mouse or keyboard event. Or maybe an Ajax request, XHR or even something else. All these mechanisms triggers Change Detection to run. When Change Detection is triggered it checks if properties of the class have changed, if so - it updates the view.

Now in your case when component loads, callback `.subscribe(res => this.event = res);` haven't yet accrued, so `this.event` is still undefined. But if you conditionally state in template `*ngIf="event"` Angular will ignore that field in template and will not throw any errors. And when `.subscribe(res => this.event = res);` is executed and then causes a Change Detection to be triggered, it checks all properties (including `this.event`) if they have changed. And because `this.event` was `undefined` before and now has some value, it rerenders the view, but this time `*ngIf="event"` will return `true` so the value will be displayed.

p.s. your solution is good. No need to worry. If you have heard about the `?` (Elvis operator), it serves the exact same reason - to check if value is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is possible that your variable event is not an instance of `IEvent`. Or that perhaps it is is not accessible to your child component. Try defining

```
event: Ievent;
```

in your parent `event.component.ts`. Instead of

```
let event;
```